# Text in front of a background Quil canvas app

Tags: html, canvas, clojurescript, quil

I have written a Clojurescript [Quil](https://github.com/quil/quil) web page application which consists of objects floating around. This 'game' is intended to be the background to normal html text. Quil has text abilities but I have not found any examples of what I need to do. Ideally I would like to have the web page text rendered on a layer above the game, using something like [Sablono](https://github.com/r0man/sablono), and not have to be concerned about transparency issues, or any other issues - the game just being in the background!

If it is not possible to simply put Quil on a layer below then I'm reasonably sure I will be able to do it in Quil, but there will be many details to sort out: z-ordering, having the text keep its colour, having the background of the rectangle that contains a character be transparent, etc - many issues I'd like to avoid.

What is the simplest way to have an html text layer on top of a canvas layer given this setup?

The following is what I have come up with so far, that draws the text in the same function as the animation, but after the animation. Not exactly what I am looking for, but what might have to do:

```
(ns scratch.core
  (:require [quil.core :as q :include-macros true]
            [quil.middleware :as m]))

(def dark-blue [0,0,139])

(defn setup []
  (q/text-font (q/create-font "DejaVu Sans" 28 true))
  (q/frame-rate 15)
  ; Set color mode to HSB (HSV) instead of default RGB.
  ;(q/color-mode :hsb)
  ; setup function returns initial state. It contains
  ; circle color and position.
  {:color 0
   :angle 0})

(defn draw-text
  []
  (apply q/fill dark-blue)
  (q/text "The quick, brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
          100 200 300 200))

(defn update-state [state]
  ; Update sketch state by changing circle color and position.
  {:color (mod (+ (:color state) 0.7) 255)
   :angle (+ (:angle state) 0.1)})

(defn draw-state [state]
  ; Clear the sketch by filling it with light-grey color.
  (q/background 240)
  ; Set circle color.
  (q/fill (:color state) 255 255)
  ; Calculate x and y coordinates of the circle.
  (let [angle (:angle state)
        x (* 150 (* 0.4 (q/cos angle)))
        y (* 150 (* 0.4 (q/sin angle)))]
    ; Move origin point to the center of the sketch.
    (q/with-translation [(/ (q/width) 2)
                         (/ (q/height) 2)]
      ; Draw the circle.
      (q/ellipse x y 100 100)))
  ;; Simply make sure the text is drawn after the 'background'
  (draw-text))

(q/defsketch moving-ball
  :host "moving-ball"
  :size [500 500]
  :setup setup
  :update update-state
  :draw draw-state
  :middleware [m/fun-mode])
```

Comment: css `canvas{position: absolute; z-index:-1}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is this question somewhat answered [elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/3cq5hg/can_reagent_components_work_with_html_canvas/). However the workaround approach used in the question - drawing text on the canvas - will probably be good enough for my use case.